# How to properly execute hidden method

Tags: c#

I am using DrawToBitmap method to get bitmap copy of my UserControl. Turned out that in some cases DrawToBitmap cannot provide exact copy of my control's layout. That is why i decided to hide inherited member DrawToBitmap using 'new' modifier.

```
public new void DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds)
{
    // my code here
}
```

But now I am facing another problem. Code below still is executing the 'wrong' DrawToBitmap.

```
foreach( Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    ctrl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Size));
}
```

To improve it I was forced to change code this way

```
foreach( Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

    if(ctrl is MyUserControl)
        ((MyUserControl)m_target).DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Size));
    else
        ctrl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Size));
}
```

It looks pretty ugly to me. How do I fix it properly?

Comment: no, that looks pretty much how you have to do it. otherwise it just assumes that `ctrl` is of type Control, as per its definition in the foreach. Therefore it uses the version of DrawToBitmap which is defined in the `Control` class. Perfectly logical. There's no way for the code to know if it is actually an inherited type, unless you tell it that directly.  If you want it to use the version in your sub-class, then of course you have to cast `ctrl` to that type first.

Comment: That's a very interesting inheritance issue. One possible solution (rather than casting for each control type) would be to create a method using reflection that executed the `DrawToBitmap` method on the control's actual type rather than `Control`. Not an elegant solution though. Another might be to create an interface that declared `DrawToBitmap` and cast to that interface for any control implementing it. It'd give you better type safety and it's extensible but you'd still be left with code like you have in the second example there.

Comment: Such are the hassles when a method is not virtual.  Just give it a completely different name and it now becomes obvious to the reader why you had to make it ugly.

Comment: @DiskJunky: idea to use 'reflection that executed the DrawToBitmap method on the control's actual type' sounds very interesting. Thank you!